# Gap in spiral sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, oeis

OEIS sequence [A272573](https://oeis.org/A272573) describes a sequence generated in the following way:

> Start a spiral of numbers on a hexagonal tiling, with the initial hexagon as a(1) = 1. a(n) is the smallest positive integer not equal to or previously adjacent to its neighbors.

[image: A272573]

The sequence begins `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,6,8,...`.

If you look at the scatterplot, there appears to be a very sparse region. [image: Scatterplot, A272573]

## Question

I'm curious if there is some heuristic which explains why this gap appears. (In particular, the heuristic should also account for the fact that such a gap does not appear in [A260643](https://oeis.org/A260643), the analogous sequence on a square grid.)

Comment: Very interesting.  Did you use the ruby code from OEIS (which I can't read) or a program in some other language?  If the latter, would you post it?

Comment: Here's a post on [Code Golf Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/177493/53884) with two other programs that corroborate the Ruby program. The code there is (deliberately) hard to read, but they have explanations.

Comment: Thanks.  I hate code golf as  a general rule (possibly because I'm no good at it), but I'll take a look.

Comment: Each cell has 6 neighbors and 12 level 2 neighbors, so how can its value be more than 19? Why the scatter plot looks unbounded? What am I missing?

Comment: @TodorMarkov: I think "equal to or previously adjacent to its neighbors" means "equal to or previously adjacent to a cell with the same value as a neighboring cell".